# rsyslog set 3 Access Points to log to same file?

Tags: 12.04

I've been looking at examples of rsyslogs but most seems too programmer centric for me.

I need 10.10.10.12, 10.10.10.13, 10.10.10.14 to get 1 shared log file.

This gives me the log I want into my main /var/log/syslog

```
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

I tried adding this, but It didn't work.

```
if $fromhost-ip == '10.10.10.12' then /var/log/aps.log
& ~

if $fromhost-ip == '10.10.10.13' then /var/log/aps.log
& ~

if $fromhost-ip == '10.10.10.14' then /var/log/aps.log
& ~
```

I updated my code with `==` as it makes more scene, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: and `if $fromhost-ip == '10.10.10.12' then /var/log/aps.log` ? Since you provide a full IP ;)

Comment: updated post... no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two changes i used $hostname
I changed permissions to 777 on the log file.

It works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `if $fromhost-ip isequal '10.10.10.14' then /var/log/aps.log` ?

You can also try `:HOSTNAME, isequal, '10.10.10.14' /var/log/aps.log`...

Comment: isequal does not work